# send multiple RTK query request in response of another RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I am new to RTK Query and when I fetch some data from an endpoint I get a response of an array of objects for each id of item in the list I have to call another API to get the details of each item.
but I do not know have to achieve this.

for example:

```
query: () => '/posts'; // response is ==> [{id: 21, title:'Hello world'}]
```

and the for the details of the post with an id of 21

```
query: (id) => `post/${id}/detail`; // response { description:'', img:'', ... }
```

I need to show all posts with details. and for that, I have to get all the details on the list first and then return the result from query to later show it on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came up with this so far

```
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import axiosBaseQuery from 'api/axiosBaseQuery';
import axios from 'services/request';

export const postsApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api/portfolio',
    baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery(),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getUserPosts: builder.query({
            async queryFn() {
                // get a random user
                const postsList = await axios.get('/posts');
                if (postsList.error) return { error: postsList.error };
                // const result = await axios.get(`/market/instruments/${item.refId}/summary`);
                const endpoints = postsList.data.map((item) =>
                    axios.get(`/post/${item.id}/details`)
                );
                let error = null;
                let data = null;
                try {
                    data = await Promise.all(endpoints).then((res) => {
                        return res.map((item, index) => {
                            return { ...item.data, ...postsList.data[index] };
                        });
                    });
                } catch (err) {
                    error = err;
                }

                return data ? { data } : { error };
            }
        })
    })
});

export const { useGetUserPostsQuery } = postsApi;
```